# connect to mysql db using Zend_Db_Adapter_PDO_Mysql class

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

How to connect to mysql db correctly? In my `application.ini` file, I have put all the db details:

```
[master]
adapter = PDO_MYSQL
params.host = localhost
params.username = root
params.password = ''
params.dbname = accounts_db
```

I want to get these details and connect to my db.

Comment: I doubt its urgent, and this is just lazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one its work

```
resources.db.adapter = PDO_MYSQL
resources.db.params.host = localhost
resources.db.params.username = root
resources.db.params.password = 
resources.db.params.dbname = accounts_db
```

In my site it will work perfectly

Comment: still you are not able to connect then let me know

Answer (score 1):

When it's the default mysql database adapter you can add the line at the bottom, in that case it will be auto. used in Zend_Db_Table objects etc.

```
resources.db.adapter="pdo_mysql"
resources.db.params.host="localhost"
resources.db.params.username="username"
resources.db.params.password="pass"
resources.db.params.dbname="dbname"                       
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter=true
```

On the otherside you can fetch the adapter at any place with

```
Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Zend Framework is not the easiest framework to start application development. My best advice is to start reading the [quickstart documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.html), especially chapters dealing with [Zend_Application](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.html), [Zend_Db](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.html), [Zend_Layout](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.layout.html) and of course [Zend_Controller](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.html).

To answer your question, adding database configuration to `application.ini` isn't setting up the db connection. You should *bootstrap* an application resource using:

```
[production]

; Database (production)
resources.db.adapter = "pdo_mysql"
resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
resources.db.params.username = "my_user_who_is_not_root"
resources.db.params.password = "my_strong_password"
resources.db.params.dbname = "accounts_db"
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true

; Other configurations
; ...

[development : production]

; Database (development settings)
resources.db.params.username = "root"
resources.db.params.password = ""
resources.db.params.dbname = "accounts_db_dev"
```

At this point, **your database connection is ready to query the server**.

Into your controllers (or anything else), you can retrieve the connection using:

```
Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
```

You could also within your `Bootstrap` add a reference to the connection to the `Zend_Register`:

```
protected function _initDbRegister()
{
    $db = $this->bootstrap('Db')->getResource('Db');
    Zend_Register::set('Zend_Db', $db);
}
```

Later, you could call `Zend_Register::get('Zend_Db')` to get the instance.